# Questions about disconnected mode with SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have two questions about the code below that where I'm using the `Dataset` to copy the database to the memory.

First question: I wonder why I can't use this code for the connection:

```
connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DALLayer.Properties.Settings.AnimalMotelConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

I get this error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please explain what I have missed. I use the name string in the app.config. Now my connection is hardcoded like in the code below and that works.

Second question: When I use the dataset, I guess I can only read and do things within the sql command that I have. When I want to change, add or delete, I have to use another sql command and a new dataset?

```
 public void Test()
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        string connectionsString = null;
        string sql = null;

        connectionsString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\AnimalMotel.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        sql = "SELECT * From Guests";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionsString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            connection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[1]), "This is only a test!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I have to leave the computer for a couple of hours, but I will follow up the answers later. Thanks so far!